# WebAPI return an IQueryable that is like an array is javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have one WebAPI method which returns IQueryable of a 'complex' object written like this:

```
[Route("api/INV_API/deptSelect")]
public IQueryable<DEPTNAME_DESCR> GetDistinctDeptSelect([FromUri] string q)
{
        if (q != null)
        {
                         var query = (from d in db.DEPTs
                         where d.DESCR.Contains(q) || d.DEPTNAME.Contains(q)
                         select new DEPTNAME_DESCR { DEPTNAME = d.DEPTNAME, DESCR = d.DESCR }).Distinct();


            return query;

        }
        else
        {
            var query = (from d in db.DEPTs
                         select new DEPTNAME_DESCR { DEPTNAME = d.DEPTNAME, DESCR = d.DESCR }).Distinct();


            return query;
        }
}
```

When using AJAX to GET from this method, I receive some sort of javascript array like this:

[image]

I have another WebAPI method which I am trying to return a `IQueryable<string>` form originally a List of string :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/INV_API/requesterIdSelect2")]
public IQueryable<string> GetListOfUserId([FromUri] string q)
{
   var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SelectUSERIDFromSM @searchterm", new SqlParameter("@searchterm", q)).ToList();

        return result.AsQueryable<string>();
}
```

However, when I inspect what is returned from AJAX GET, it looks like this: 
[image]

I am trying to understand what I did wrongly in the second method. Do I have to serialise whatever I am returning ? Or is there something wrong with my SQL query itself.

I will provide more information if this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Update your method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/INV_API/requesterIdSelect2")]
public IEnumerable<string> GetListOfUserId([FromUri] string q)
{
   var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SelectUSERIDFromSM @searchterm", new SqlParameter("@searchterm", q)).ToList();

        return result;
}
```

IQueryable represent a stored query and not the results returned by query. For executing the query you have to execute method like `ToList` or `Distinct` like you have in your first code snippet